# Vue 2 add slot to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am running into an issue with *Vue 2*. I have a main component called *search.vue* `<product-search></product-search>`. This component has a property called `:view` , this view can be table, small columns, medium columns and more. All those views are custom components: `table_view.vue`, `small_columns.vue` etc. In my views, I have a slot called actions `<slot name="actions"></slot>`. Now I want to add actions from to the main component (product-search.vue) and pass them to the view components. As example:

Does anybody knows how i can achieve this?

I've reduced the amount of code for better reading.

### blank_page.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <search-product :multiple="false" :shop="shop" v-model="items" display="table" :modal="false">
                    <template slot="table-actions">
                        <div>Here some extra actions</div>
                    </template>
            </search-product>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: {
                shop: {}
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    items: []
                };
            }
        }
    </script>
```

### search.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <template>
                <component v-bind:is="getDisplay()" :multiple="multiple" :items="items" v-model="selectedItems"></component>

            </template>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import SearchButton from './search-button.vue';
        import SearchInput from './input.vue';
        import DisplayTable from './displays/table.vue';
        import DisplaySmallGrid from './displays/small-grid.vue';
        import DisplayMediumGrid from './displays/medium-grid.vue';
        import DisplayLargeGrid from './displays/large-grid.vue';

        export default {
            components: {
                searchButton: SearchButton,
                searchInput: SearchInput,
                displayTable: DisplayTable,
                displaySmallGrid: DisplaySmallGrid,
                displayMediumGrid: DisplayMediumGrid,
                displayLargeGrid: DisplayLargeGrid,
            },
            props: {
                modal: {
                    default: false
                },
                multiple: {
                    default: true
                },
                value: {},
                shop: {},
                display: {
                    default: 'table'
                }
            },
            watch: {
                selectedItems(data) {
                    this.$emit('input', data);
                }
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    q: '',
                    items: [],
                    selectedItems: [],
                    modalOpen: false,
                    templates: {
                        DisplayTable
                    }
                };
            },
            methods: {
                getDisplay() {
                    return 'display' + this.display.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.display.slice(1);
                },
                toggleModal() {
                    this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

### table_view.vue

```
<template>
    <div :class="panel ? 'card' : ''">
        <div :class="panel ? 'card-body' : ''">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in items">
                    <td v-text="item.id"></td>

                    <td>
                        <slot name="table-actions"></slot>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            items: {},
            value: {},
            multiple: {},
            panel: {
                default: true
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 solutions: Passing it from parent to grandchild as props through the child component.

parent:data: yourAction => child:props:yourAction => grandchild:props:yourAction

and then use v-html to render it in case it has some html tags

or pass it as props to the child and use slot there to pass it to the grandchild.

## First solution

### blank_page.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <search-product :multiple="false" :shop="shop" v-model="items" display="table" :modal="false" :yourAction:"yourAction">

            </search-product>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: {
                shop: {}
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    items: [],
                    yourAction: "Here some stuff"
                };
            }
        }
    </script>
```

### search.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <template>
                <component v-bind:is="getDisplay()" :multiple="multiple" :items="items" v-model="selectedItems" :yourAction="yourAction"></component>

            </template>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import SearchButton from './search-button.vue';
        import SearchInput from './input.vue';
        import DisplayTable from './displays/table.vue';
        import DisplaySmallGrid from './displays/small-grid.vue';
        import DisplayMediumGrid from './displays/medium-grid.vue';
        import DisplayLargeGrid from './displays/large-grid.vue';

        export default {
            components: {
                searchButton: SearchButton,
                searchInput: SearchInput,
                displayTable: DisplayTable,
                displaySmallGrid: DisplaySmallGrid,
                displayMediumGrid: DisplayMediumGrid,
                displayLargeGrid: DisplayLargeGrid,
            },
            props: {
                yourAction:{
                default:""
                },
                modal: {
                    default: false
                },
                multiple: {
                    default: true
                },
                value: {},
                shop: {},
                display: {
                    default: 'table'
                }
            },
            watch: {
                selectedItems(data) {
                    this.$emit('input', data);
                }
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    q: '',
                    items: [],
                    selectedItems: [],
                    modalOpen: false,
                    templates: {
                        DisplayTable
                    }
                };
            },
            methods: {
                getDisplay() {
                    return 'display' + this.display.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.display.slice(1);
                },
                toggleModal() {
                    this.modalOpen = !this.modalOpen;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

### table_view.vue

```
<template>
    <div :class="panel ? 'card' : ''">
        <div :class="panel ? 'card-body' : ''">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in items">
                    <td v-text="item.id"></td>

                    <td v-html="yourAction">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            yourAction,
            items: {},
            value: {},
            multiple: {},
            panel: {
                default: true
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

## Second solution

blank_page.vue: same as the first example I gave you, you pass your action as props

search.vue: you pass the props to the slot as you did in the example of blank_page.vue

table_view.vue : remain the same

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you need to use the item from the slot

Comment: From what I understood, you are trying to insert some Html or text into the grandchild component. what kind of items do you want to insert there?